# How to merge various columns from three CSV files?

Tags: python, pandas

I have three CSV files:

**file 1**

```
id,code
1,a
2,b
3,c
4,d
```

**file 2**

```
no,count,sum,class
3,567,55562,Y
5,673,66259,L
1,674,78256,Y
4,344,56789,Y
```

**file 3**

```
record,mean,median
3,5437,553
2,67233,664
1,67234,785
4,34423,556
```

I would like to merge `count` and `sum` from **file 2** with **file 1** if `id` and `no` match and merge `mean` and `median` from **file 3** with **file 1** if `id` and `record` match. I tried the below code but the final output file has lots of full fields even though they match with `id`.

```
df = pd.concat([file1, file2,file3], join_axes=[df.index])
df= df.drop["class"]
```

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: How to create a [mcve]. Specially: **what** errors do you run into?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you need set indexes from first column in [`read_csv`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.read_csv.html):

```
import pandas as pd
from pandas.compat import StringIO

temp=u"""id,code
1,a
2,b
3,c
4,d"""
#after testing replace 'StringIO(temp)' to 'filename.csv'
file1 = pd.read_csv(StringIO(temp), index_col=[0])
print (file1)

temp=u"""
no,count,sum,class
3,567,55562,Y
5,673,66259,L
1,674,78256,Y
4,344,56789,Y"""
#after testing replace 'StringIO(temp)' to 'filename.csv'
file2 = pd.read_csv(StringIO(temp), index_col=[0])
print (file2)

temp=u"""
record,mean,median
3,5437,553
2,67233,664
1,67234,785
4,34423,556"""
#after testing replace 'StringIO(temp)' to 'filename.csv'
file3 = pd.read_csv(StringIO(temp), index_col=[0])

print (file3)
```

---

```
df = pd.concat([file1, file2,file3], axis=1).drop("class", axis=1)
print (df)
  code  count      sum     mean  median
1    a  674.0  78256.0  67234.0   785.0
2    b    NaN      NaN  67233.0   664.0
3    c  567.0  55562.0   5437.0   553.0
4    d  344.0  56789.0  34423.0   556.0
5  NaN  673.0  66259.0      NaN     NaN
```

Also if indexes are not set in `read_csv` is necessary add [`set_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.set_index.html):

```
import pandas as pd
from pandas.compat import StringIO

temp=u"""id,code
1,a
2,b
3,c
4,d"""
#after testing replace 'StringIO(temp)' to 'filename.csv'
file1 = pd.read_csv(StringIO(temp))
print (file1)

temp=u"""
no,count,sum,class
3,567,55562,Y
5,673,66259,L
1,674,78256,Y
4,344,56789,Y"""
#after testing replace 'StringIO(temp)' to 'filename.csv'
file2 = pd.read_csv(StringIO(temp))
print (file2)

temp=u"""
record,mean,median
3,5437,553
2,67233,664
1,67234,785
4,34423,556"""
#after testing replace 'StringIO(temp)' to 'filename.csv'
file3 = pd.read_csv(StringIO(temp))

print (file3)
```

---

```
df=pd.concat([file1.set_index('id'), file2.set_index('no'),file3.set_index('record')],axis=1)
       .drop("class", axis=1)
print (df)
  code  count      sum     mean  median
1    a  674.0  78256.0  67234.0   785.0
2    b    NaN      NaN  67233.0   664.0
3    c  567.0  55562.0   5437.0   553.0
4    d  344.0  56789.0  34423.0   556.0
5  NaN  673.0  66259.0      NaN     NaN
```

Or for inner join add `join='inner'` to [`concat`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.concat.html):

```
df = pd.concat([file1.set_index('id'),
                file2.set_index('no'),
                file3.set_index('record')], join='inner', axis=1).drop("class", axis=1)
print (df)
  code  count    sum   mean  median
3    c    567  55562   5437     553
1    a    674  78256  67234     785
4    d    344  56789  34423     556
```

Comment: i still receive output with blank fields. foreg) 3,c,,,,,,

Comment: Hmmm, it seems you need inner join, please check last edit.

Comment: thanks . i have similar csv file n when i tried it, i got the error - ValueError: Shape of passed values is (35, 7824), indices imply (35, 309)

Comment: What is `print (file2.info())` ?

Comment: And what is separator in csv for file2?

Comment: For file 2, Int64Index: 7098 entries, 0 to 18933
Data columns (total 4 columns):
no        7098 non-null object
count      7098 non-null object
sum        7098 non-null object
class    7098 non-null object
dtypes: object(4)
memory usage: 166.4+ KB

Comment: for file 3, Data columns (total 3 columns):
record          3680 non-null object
mean    3680 non-null object
median    3680 non-null object
dtypes: object(3)
memory usage: 86.2+ KB
None

Comment: for file 1,RangeIndex: 7867 entries, 0 to 7866
Data columns (total 27 columns): dtypes: object(27)
memory usage: 829.8+ KB
None

Comment: all three file separated by comma

Comment: It seems some problem in data files. Are data confidental?

Comment: yes. i am afraid so. What other details you need regarding the data?

Comment: Hmmm, without data it is more problematic. But I try. So first do you try first solution with `index_col=[0]` ? If yes, what is `print (file1.index.dtype)`, `print (file2.index.dtype)` and `print (file3.index.dtype)` ?

Comment: i use header=0 instead

Comment: It is difference. `index_col` mean set index from first column by position. So it set index from column `id, no, record`. I think there was problem.